# Copy location of Print Area from one File to another using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a program that already copies a sheet from a Template Library to another file where it can be used. Is there a way to get it to also copy the location of the print area in the template and make the new file have the same print area?

```
Workbooks("TestLibrary.xlsx").Sheets(Size).Range("A1:AO311").Copy_ 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNum).Range("A1")

Workbooks("TestLibrary.xlsx").Sheets(Size).Range("A1:AO311").Copy_
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNum).Range("A1:AO311").PasteSpecial_ 
Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
```

Comment: What is your code ?

Comment: Edit: I put it in the original post so its easier to read

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNum).PageSetup.PrintArea = Workbooks("TestLibrary.xlsx").Sheets(Size).PageSetup.PrintArea
```